# Как удалить объект из массива стейта?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zustand

Использую стейт менеджер zustand.
В стейте массив объектов, по клику на кнопку необходимо удалить объект массива стейта. А данный код удаляет весь массив из стейта...Не могу понять почему не удаляется конкретный объект. необходимо удалить по клику на кнопку:  {
"name": "Saski Baskonia",
"price": "4"
} или любой другой добавленный объект.
имею текущий массив в стейте:

[
{
"name": "FC Bayern München",
"price": "1.42"
},
{
"name": "Saski Baskonia",
"price": "4"
},
{
"name": "Virtus Segafredo Bologna",
"price": "1.8"
}
]

код в сторе:

````
const createCouponSlice = (set, get) =>({
   marketInfoList: [],
   addToMarketInfoList: (name, price) => {
    const newTeam = {name, price}
    set({
        marketInfoList: Array.from(new Set(([...get().marketInfoList, newTeam]).map(item => JSON.stringify(item)))).map(item => JSON.parse(item))
    })
   },
   removeToMarketInfoList: (id) => {
    set({ 
    marketInfoList: get().marketInfoList.filter(market => market.id != id)
    })
   },
}) 
export default createCouponSlice;```

код в компоненте, из которой необходимо удалить объект:

``` const removeToMarketInfoList = useStore((state) => state.removeToMarketInfoList)

    return (  
                <div>{marketInfoList.map((market) => (
                <div key={market.id}>
                    <Typography >{market.price}{' '}{market.name}
                    <button onClick={() => removeToMarketInfoList(market.id)}>x</button>
                    </Typography>
                    
                </div>
               ))}
````

Comment: Так ты посмотри с чем имеешь дело `console.log(get().marketInfoList)` и что потом будет возвращено `console.log(get().marketInfoList.filter(market => market.id != id))`

Comment: а откуда взялось id?
У тебя ведь `const newTeam = {name, price}` никакого id нет =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется ошибка в том, что ты удаляешь по id, которого у тебя нет =)
Можно поменять логику на удаления по имени

```js
const createCouponSlice = (set, get) => ({
  marketInfoList: [],
  addToMarketInfoList: (name, price) => {
    const newTeam = { name, price };
    set({
      marketInfoList: Array.from(new Set([...get().marketInfoList, newTeam].map((item) => JSON.stringify(item)))).map(
        (item) => JSON.parse(item)
      ),
    });
  },
  removeToMarketInfoList: (name) => {
    set({
      marketInfoList: get().marketInfoList.filter((market) => market.name != name),
    });
  },
});
export default createCouponSlice;

// код в компоненте, из которой необходимо удалить объект:

const removeToMarketInfoList = useStore((state) => state.removeToMarketInfoList);

return (
  <div>
    {marketInfoList.map((market) => (
      <div key={market.name}>
        <Typography>
          {market.price} {market.name}
          <button onClick={() => removeToMarketInfoList(market.name)}>x</button>
        </Typography>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь. глаз совсем замылился...